# How to detect "missing" 'virtual' specifier in declaration of overriding virtual method?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, virtual

Suppose you have this `Base` class:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo();
};
```

You can override `foo()` in a class derived from `Base`:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo();
};
```

If, however, you "forget" '`virtual`' in the declaration of `Derived::foo()`:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo();
};
```

you get exactly the same semantics: `Derived::foo()` is virtual, although not explicitly declared so.

Now, suppose your coding standard prescribes that '`virtual`' should be mentioned explicitly in such cases.

Do you know of an easy way (in a Linux + gcc environment) to detect the missing '`virtual`' in the declaration of `Derived::foo()`?

I am not aware of any gcc warning that detects this.

Comment: `g++` feature request here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31397

Comment: I suppose fixing the broken coding standard isn't an option? That seems like a better approach than breaking the compiler to match.

Comment: `clang-modernize` allow to add `override` in the code.

Answer (score -2):

Use the C++11 [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/override) feature.
The compiler will output a warning or error if it's not appropriate.

Instead of relying on an error prone coding standard, let the compiler do that check for you.

To answer the comments below, you must take into account both cases:

1. Put an *override* qualifier on a method will output an error if the base class method with the same signature and name is not virtual.
2. It will also an output an error if it does not become virtual in the hierarchy.

So this code:

```
struct A
{
   void foo();
   virtual int bar();
};

struct B : A
{
   virtual void foo(); // If you add override here, it errors, if you forget "virtual" it errors too, later in C
   int bar() override;
};

// Write this for each subclass:
struct C : B
{
   void foo() override; // Fails if B does not have "virtual" keyword
};
```

Agreed, it's tedious since you must replicate all the signatures of the classes for every subclass (no need for implementation through). So, if you want to enforce all your children to explicitely override all virtual methods they "override" from the base class, you need to "disable" the inheritance of the child class to the base class, like this:

```
#ifndef CheckVirtual
   #define WITH_BASE(X) : public X
#else
   #define WITH_BASE(X) 
#endif

struct A
{
   virtual int bar();
   virtual void baz();
};

//==== \/ This is the hostile code to test \/ ========
struct B WITH_BASE(A)
{
   virtual int bar();
   void baz();
};
//==== End of hostile code ====



//==== \/ Start of enforcer code, you must have one enforcer header per base class to check for 
// Notice that Enforcer must reproduce interface of A
struct Enforcer : B
{
   int bar() override;
   void baz() override; // Error here if CheckVirtual is defined, since B::baz is not virtual.
};

// Or better, some sugar, if you have plenty of child of A, with some macro magic:
template <typename T>
struct VirtualEnforcer_ : T
{
    #include "Your_A_Interface_Here"
};
#define EnforceVirtual(X) VirtualEnforcer_<X> assertVirtual ## X ()

EnforceVirtual(B);
EnforceVirtual(AnotherChildOfA);
```

Comment: That's not what he is asking

Comment: That is exactly the opposite of that what is asked for. The question is then: How to find all missing override/final declarations! Indeed, virtual in derived classes is messy in c++11. We also changed the coding standards that it is a must to write `override` and remove virtual. But that is not an answer of how to find all places where a `virtual` or `override` must be placed.

Comment: @Matt McNabb: You are right, that's not what I was asking. That said, I am impressed that you were able to deduce ("**he**") from my user name alone (user1387866) that I am a male user :)

Comment: clang has a tool (clang-modernize) to add automatically `override`

Comment: @Klaus: Well, see my updated answer. It explains how to adapt the feature to the need.

Comment: @user1387866 an estimate based on statistical distribution